# How to append dataframe to a datasource using spark without duplicating data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I'm trying to save new a dataframe to a datasource using append. the issue is that the dataframe already has some lines that are duplicates in the datasource.

```
        df.write \
        .format('bigquery') \
        .option('table', 'datasource') \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()
```

How ca I do this without duplication ?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean you want that if a line already exist in the target, you do not write it, right ?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions for that.

## 1st one: join

You compare your current data with the previous one and write only the line which do not exist.

```py
df_old = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("table", "datasource").load()

df = df.join(
   df_old,
   how="left_anti",
   on="", # add proper join condition here
)
```

## 2nd one: concatenate and re-write

You concatenate both old and new, dedup the data, then rewrite them

```py
df_old = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("table", "datasource").load()`

df.unionAll(df_old).distinct().write(...)
```